# Table header repeated

Tags: php, html, database

I have made a table that shows database info in a html table. The table headers gets repeated for every row. Is there a way to make the header only show on top of the table.

```
      <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Login-ID</th>
      <th>Konto typ</th>
      <th>Lösenord</th>
      <th>Skapad</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>' . $row['ID']. '</td>
<td>' . $row['user_id']. '</td>
<td>' . $row['user_type']. '</td>
<td>' . $row['user_pwd']. '</td>
<td>' . $row['user_created']. '</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the part that you get data from database?

Comment: It seems that it's inside a loop. Please, show full code.

Comment: The loop should just be around the `<tr>`, not around `<table>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<table>` should not be inside the loop.

```
echo '<div>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Login-ID</th>
          <th>Konto typ</th>
          <th>Lösenord</th>
          <th>Skapad</th>
        </tr>
    ';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $row['ID']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['user_id']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['user_type']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['user_pwd']. '</td>
            <td>' . $row['user_created']. '</td>
        </tr>
        ';
}
echo '</table>
    </div>';
```

Comment: Now let's only hope it stops there ;-)

Comment: Oh, you've some missing semi-colons here. I know I could edit, but you have to work for that tenner I gave you ;-) Edit: *grazie!*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Wow, you're really putting me through my paces the past few days. :)

Comment: I came very close to completely redoing it in `<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>` style.

Comment: I make a pretty good 1st mate/right-hand man and crane operator helper ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that'd of been a good redo, but that gets them out of the woods :) Edit: Let's only hope they don't meet up with the big bad wolf!